# IText Object above Overlay Image

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

In my canvas I have an overlay image using **setOverlayImage**  method from Fabric.js canvas library.

I have the need to place an IText object above my already set overlay image, but the IText object always appear behind my overlay image.

Is there some way to accomplish that using Fabric.js?

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. "OverlayImage" is an overlay over all other objects.

Why you need that?
Can you use "BackgroundImage" instead?